# Set `pytest` log options in `contest.py` based on a custom command line flag

Tags: python, pytest

I want to add a custom command-line flag to pytest which is responsible for setting multiple command-line options in `conftest.py`. (I don't want to set these options in `pyproject.toml`)

So basically, I want the following two commands too be equivalent

```
pytest -o log_cli=1 -o log_cli_level=10 -o log_format="%(message)s"

pytest --vmtrace
```

Now I have figured out how to register the `--vmtrace` option inside `conftest.py` as well as how I can access the value passed to it.

I am however, unable to figure out how to set the values of the `log_cli` `log_cli_level` and `log_format` options as required in the command above.

Here is what my `conftest.py` file currently looks like. Please suggest, what should replace the comments in the `pytest_configure` function.

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--vmtrace", dest='vmtrace', default=1, action='store_const', const=10, help="Run trace")


def pytest_configure(config):
    if config.getoption("vmtrace", default=1) == 10:
        # Set the log_cli option to 1
        # Set the log_cli_level option to 10
        # Set the log_format option to "%(message)s"
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this one out. Posting here in case someone else needs this.

The solution seems to me to be a bit hacky but it works. `log_cli` seems to be unavailable here but the other two parameters can be set. The `log_cli` parameter is set to `True` when the `log_cli_level` is set.

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    if config.getoption("vmtrace", default=1) == 10:
        config.option.__dict__["log_cli_level"] = "10"
        config.option.__dict__["log_format"] = "%(message)s"
```